# How to detect arguments passed to function if they are not defined in the function's input?

Tags: javascript, arguments

is it possible to detect arguments passed to a function if they are not explicitly defined in the function?

for example:

```js
function test(){

    //is it possible to see a, b and c from inside this function without defining them in the function's arguments?

};

test(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

```js
function test(){
  console.log([...arguments]);
};

test('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript yes above we have an argument

```
for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    document.write( arguments[i]);
}
```

in php we have two function for  checking dynamic argument in PHP function:
1.func_num_args()  we can get how many arguments
2.func_get_arg(1)  we can get argument starting from zero.

```
 $args= func_num_args();
 for($i=0;$i> $args;$i++) {
 echo  $i+1. " - argument is: " . func_get_arg($i) . "\n";
 }
```

Comment: This is a question about JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct.  I haven't seen this.